# Node.js and Express - BadRequestError: request aborted

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing a performance test on a node.js api i have created.

There is a POST endpoint that takes in an image as an input in base64. So the request payload is quite large, my test case image is around 7-8mb.

When im running my performance test with 10 users concurrently, i get the following error:

**Request**:

```
{"log_id":"db0ac1d0-cafe-11e9-afec-e91ff7e323e3","level":"info","request":{"method":"POST","path":"<removed>","url":"<api_url_removed>","body":{},"forward_for":"<removed>","content_type":"application/json","content_length":"7687038"},"message":"Received","log_type":"request","timestamp":"2019-08-30 08:19:15"}
```

**Error:**

> BadRequestError: request aborted
>       at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:10)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:449:9)
>       at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:442:3)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
>       at TCP._handle.close (net.js:600:12)

I can see 10-20 of these requests with the same error. They all have unique ids. Obviously its normal that this many requests are being made because im running a performance test.

My question is why is node.js/express throwing this BadRequestError and how can i handle it.

**app.ts**

```
class App {

    public app: express.Application;
    public config: any;
    public log = Logger;

    constructor() {

        this.app = express();

        this.errors();
        this.environment();
        this.database();
        this.middleware();
        this.routes();

    }

    private environment(): void {

        this.config = new Config();

    }

    private errors(): void {

        // TODO: Remove ( Handled By Winston );
        // process.on("uncaughtException", (ex) => {
        //     process.exit(1);
        // });

        process.on("unhandledRejection", (ex) => {
            throw ex;
        });


    }

    private database(): void {

        const uri: string = this.config.db.uri;
        const options: mongoose.ConnectionOptions = this.config.db.options;

        mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
            () => {
                this.log.info("MongoDB Successfully Connected On: " + this.config.db.uri);
            },
            (err: any) => {
                this.log.error("MongoDB Error:", err);
                this.log.info("%s MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.");
                throw err;
            },

        );

    }

    private middleware(): void {

        const logs = new LogMiddleware(this.app);

        this.app.use(cors());

        this.app.use(morgan("combined", {

            skip: (req, res) => {
                return (req.originalUrl === "/api/v2/healthcheck") ? true : false;
            },
            stream: {
                write: (meta: any) => {
                },
            },
        }));

        this.app.use(express.json({limit: "16mb"}));
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "16mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
        this.app.use(passport.initialize());


    }

    private routes(): void {

        const routes = new Routes(this.app);
    }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you expect the application to start in exactly the following manner:

```
this.app = express();

this.errors();
this.environment();
this.database();
this.middleware();
this.routes();
```

Node.js has an async nature, database connection does an I/O operation and it will be done the last one. It is very likely your application already start to process requests before you have a db connection established. So in some of your controllers/routes, you throw that 400 error.

What you need to do is to start your application when you have all your baking services like DB connected and running.

Comment: right, i understand your point. It does not explain that this error occurs after i know the server has been started. I know this because i can see the logs of the db connection has been made. After and only after i run the test which gives my problem.

Comment: My app is already running on a test environment in the cloud so i can see it has already been started, sometime after i will start the test manually.

Answer (score -3):

this issue is related to the body-parser package setup

here is a basic setup as mentioned in the documentation

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

also you can find the link to thet code here [adding a generic JSON and URL-encoded](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic)